# Calculate difference in date by indicator variable

Tags: r, date, datetime, data-manipulation

Suppose I have the following example dataframe with each id observation containing 1 group 1 observation (reference value):

```
id  date             group
1   15-01-2022        1
1   15-01-2022        2
1   16-01-2022        2
1   20-01-2022        2
2   18-01-2022        1
2   20-01-2022        2
2   27-01-2022        2
```

I want to calculate a column for the difference between each date for ids in group 1 vs group 2:

```
id  date             group  diff
1   15-01-2022        1      NA
1   15-01-2022        2      0
1   16-01-2022        2      1
1   20-01-2022        2      5
2   18-01-2022        1      NA
2   20-01-2022        2      2
2   27-01-2022        2      9
```

Comment: Is there always only one `group = 1` row per `id`?

Comment: Yes, this is the case where there is a reference date or index date and am trying to find how close the other observations are to the reference date.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(diff = date - date[group == 1]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This assumes your `date` is already of class `Date`. It will put a `0` rather than a `NA` for the first value. If you need the `NA` then you can instead use:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(diff = ifelse(group == 1, NA, date - date[group == 1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```